# How do I prevent Java's Mongo driver from escaping quotes in queries

Tags: java, arrays, json, mongodb, escaping

### The case

So I'm trying to execute a query to a Mongo database using Java. In shell, the query I'm talking about looks like this:

```
db.myCollection.find({ "array" : { "$in" : [ "foo" , "bar" ]}});
```

The query is put together in Java like so:

```
DBCursor cursor = myCollection.find(new BasicDBObject("array", new BasicDBObject("$in", items)));
```

Here, variable **items** is defined as a String[], which is passed from somewhere else. It can hold any value, but in this example it contains the following elements:

```
"foo", "bar";
```

### The problem

This is where the problem starts. Calling

```
cursor.getQuery()
```

returns

```
{ "array" : { "$in" : [ "\"foo\"" , "\"bar\"" ]}}
```

which won't give back any results. As you can see, the Mongo driver for Java added quotes and escaped them.

### I tried

1. Copying the array, and making sure everything is trimmed off. Then pass it to the query.

   ```
   String[] test = new String[items.length];
   for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
       test[i] = items[i].trim();
   }
   ```

   Didn't work.
2. Now here's some real magic for y'all! I tried initializing the string just before the query like this:

   ```
   String[] items = new String[]{ "foo", "bar" };
   ```

   When I initialize it like that, Mongo doesn't escape the quotes and the query works.

---

So I'd like to know what kind of trickery this is. And how I could solve this.

Thank you all for reading!

Comment: Does your `items` array actually contains literal strings `"foo"` and `"bar"`? It the quotes are part of the string, they will be escaped, and it's a proper behavior.

Comment: @PawelVeselov Well, I'll be darned. While debugging, I outputted the results to the console and completely missed the fact they had quotes around them. You, sir, just provided me with the answer. Tip of the hat!

Comment: If that fixed your issue, ask @PawelVeselov to provide that as an answer, or if he doesn't, post it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't attempt to prevent Mongo driver from escaping the string literals. Escaping is done to ensure that the final json or bson is syntactically correct. AFAIK, it's not possible to alter how Mongo driver formats final messages to the server, which is reasonable since it's properly implementing server protocol.

In your particular case, your intent was to use string literals `foo` and `bar`, yet your data contained literals `"foo"` and `"bar"` instead, causing the logical problems you were observing.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is correct,

For the similar case I applied following trick, if anybody need a solution for quoted expressions I'm dropping below my solution.

```
BasicDBObject objectJsonKey = BasicDBObject.parse(quotedStrKey);
BasicDBObject filterCondition = new BasicDBObject("_id", objectJsonKey);
```

`quotedStrKey` is my compound json object `_id` with double quotes `"`